# finding discrète coordinate of Intersection of two convex polygon?

Tags: convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry, discrete-geometry, intersection-theory

I seek for cartésien coordinate of vertex's of the intersection area between two polygons ?
We have two convex polygon's P & Q such that : all vertex of P (resp. Q) are in 2D cartésien plane.
I proceeded like that :

- 1 : executing the O'rourke algorithm . // will générate the new convex polygon associated to the intersection of P & Q.
- 2 : Some vetrex haven't an integer coordinate , so every point with non-cartésien coordinate will générate Two other points (with integer coordinate) inculuded to both P and Q.
- 3 : calculing the convex hull of the resulting points set.

### Example

[image]

Can any one help me to find (an algorithm) out the blue Polygon as a result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An algorithm is described in this book (and C & Java code is available):

> *Computational Geometry in C*. ([webpage link](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/compgeom.html).)

---

[image: ConvexConvexInt]

---

It's trickier than one might imagine.

---

**Added**. Now I see that the OP wants the largest lattice convex polygon contained
in the intersection of $P$ & $Q$.
Perhaps the best method is to intersect $P$ & $Q$ with horizontal lattice lines,
find the extreme lattice points on each such line contained in both, and then take the convex hull
of all these extreme points.

Comment: I tried to understand a bit how is the algorithm described in this book. 
But I seek a kind of discretization of the set of points of the intersection of two convex polygons.
because the research during intersection point we just have points of non-integer coordinates. this is the problem how to ovoide this ?

Comment: @LimemeIbnAli: You cannot avoid non-integer coordinates, as your own example illustrates. Unless you want to approximate the intersection, rather than obtain the exact intersection.

Comment: how it can be done if the two polygons are ConvexLatticePolygon ? I mean by avoid non-integer coordinates, from the intersection result, is obtaining just the convex Lattice polygon. So a point with non-integer coordinate will not be defined in the case?